# in final render it remains visible from the start! The castle isn't supposed to show in the beginning

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I keyframed the (eye) on an object at the beginning of a frame but it still shows in the beginning of the frame where it is supposed only show in the middle(it does this when rendering. How to fix this?

Comment: The eye icon only controls viewport visibility. Render visibility is controlled by the camera icon.

Comment: is there a way i can animate something disappearing and reappearing?

Comment: Yes, you can keyframe the camera icon just as you did the eye icon.

Answer (score 1):

The eye icon controls the viewport visibility. The render visibility is controlled by the camera icon. Both of them can be keyframed independently of each other. This way you can have an object visible while you model, e.g. to make sure it doesn't intersect other objects, while hiding it in the render, or hide an object in the viewport, to make otherwise obscured objects easier to edit, while having it show up in the render. The screenshot below is from Blender 2.79, and in 2.8 it is slightly different, but similar enough that this image should suffice for both versions.

[image]